# appropriate data for Fp-Growth and association rules

Tags: data-mining, rapidminer

I want to choose appropriate dataset for doing fpGrowth and extracting association rules.I know that relational dataset and transactional dataset is appropriate for this task, but I want to know generally what kind of dataset is appropriate for this task ?

Answer (score 0):

You need **item sets**. No duplicates allowed, no order.

E.g. `butter, milk, bread` - it does not matter how much milk.

Also it is advisable to aggregate product **categories** instead of individual items, i.e. any kind of milk is considered to be the same.